# C# Running command prompt as admin

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm trying to run a few lines of command in an attempt to automate a work process. I've done some research online to get an idea of what I need to do. However the file remains unaffected. When I run the same command through admin command prompt, the command works.

Commands: 
echo 127.0.0.1 webedit.egnyte.com >> "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"

"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Egnyte Connect\EgnyteDrive.exe" -command add -l Egnyte -d seagen -sso use-sso -t U -c connect_immediately

I've changed the manifest to "requireAdministrator" and "highestAvailable". However there still is no change to the file.

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string command1 = "echo 127.0.0.1 webedit.egnyte.com >> \"C:\\Windows\\System32\\drivers\\etc\\hosts\"";

            Console.WriteLine("Starting Command 1: " + command1);

            Process process = new Process();
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            startInfo.Arguments = command1;
            startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
            startInfo.Verb = "runas";

            process.StartInfo = startInfo;
            process.Start();

            Console.WriteLine("Completed Command 1 ");
        }
```

The file "host" should have an added line to it.

Comment: prolly you need to add `/c` switch to `cmd` ... replace `"echo ..."` with `"/c echo ..."` **edit `/c` not `/k`** check manual why

Comment: Just curious - why do you run CMD to write a line of text to a file, when you can just open this file with `System.IO.File` and write this line?

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev but then he need to elevate his process

Comment: @Selvin Yeaah, but if the process is not elevated, then it can't run other elevated processes either, if I am correct?

Comment: with `startInfo.Verb = "runas"` it will ask user

Comment: @Selvin Oh, didn't know that, thanks! This is very handy :)